# SQL Server GROUP BY Hour over Midnight

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, group-by, sql-order-by

I'm having an issue with using GROUP BY Hour that spans over midnight.  I'm needing to order the results in order of the hour, but the returned values are listing the current days "hours" before the previous days hours.

SAMPLE TABLE:

```
DATE                LINE_NUMBER TOTAL
2019-12-03 20:38:35     1       150
2019-12-03 20:38:35     2       200
2019-12-03 20:54:35     1       175
2019-12-03 20:54:35     2       210
2019-12-03 23:58:35     1       125
2019-12-03 23:58:35     2       250

2019-12-04 00:52:35     1       155
2019-12-04 00:52:35     2       205
2019-12-04 01:32:35     1       125
2019-12-04 01:32:35     2       275
2019-12-04 01:52:35     1       145
2019-12-04 01:52:35     2       225
```

CURRENT SQL QUERY:

```
SELECT sum([TOTAL]) as HOURLY_TOTAL, LINE_NUMBER as LINE_NUMBER  
FROM PRODUCTION_LINES 
WHERE Date > '12/03/2019 15:30:00'
GROUP BY DATEPART(HOUR, [Date]), LINE_NUMBER
```

CURRENT SQL RESULTS:

```
HOURLY_TOTAL        LINE_NUMBER
155         1   (Data from current day)
270         1   (Data from current day)
325         1   (Data from previous day)
125         1   (Data from previous day)
205         2   (Data from current day)
500         2   (Data from current day)
410         2   (Data from previous day)
250         2   (Data from previous day)
```

HERE'S THE ORDER I REALLY NEED IT IN:

```
HOURLY_TOTAL        LINE_NUMBER
325         1   (Data from previous day)
125         1   (Data from previous day)
410         2   (Data from previous day)
250         2   (Data from previous day)
155         1   (Data from current day)
270         1   (Data from current day)
205         2   (Data from current day)
500         2   (Data from current day)
```

After searching for clues online, it looks like other people's issues are far more complicated than mine, so I'm not seeing any solutions that fit my case.

Answer (score 2):

You can `ORDER BY` an expression:

```
SELECT sum([TOTAL]) as HOURLY_TOTAL, LINE_NUMBER as LINE_NUMBER  
FROM PRODUCTION_LINES 
WHERE Date > '12/03/2019 15:30:00'
GROUP BY DATEPART(HOUR, [Date]), LINE_NUMBER
ORDER BY MIN(Date);
```

Actually, I'm not quite sure if the `LINE_NUMBER` should be included.  You might want:

```
ORDER BY MIN(CONVERT(DATE, Date)), LINE_NUMBER;
```

Comment: THANK YOU! The solution ended up being a slight variation of your second OrderBy suggestion, which is:

ORDER BY LINE_NUMBER, MIN(CONVERT(DATE, Date));
I just needed to swap the LINE_NUMBER and DATE in the OrderBY Clause to get what I needed. Thanks for the quick suggestion

Answer (score 0):

THANK YOU!  The solution ended up being a slight variation of your second OrderBy suggestion, which is:

```
ORDER BY LINE_NUMBER, MIN(CONVERT(DATE, Date));
```

I just needed to swap the LINE_NUMBER and DATE in the OrderBY Clause to get what I needed.  Thanks for the quick suggestion